# Is it possible to reload a page when the router receives a request to navigate to the same URL Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular5

I am new to angular. 
I've read about new features in Angular 5 - Using 'onSameUrlNavigation' now it’s possible to reload a page when the router receives a request to navigate to the same UR ? 
Currently i am using version 4.4.6. 'onSameUrlNavigation' not available in angular version 4.

Is there any other way to do the same thing in angular 4. What are the things that i have to do to accomplish this requirement.

```
providers: [
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
     onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
  })
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it with this :

```
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function(){
  return false;
};
```

this.router is the instance of your angular `Router` class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`RouteReuseStrategy`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy#shouldReuseRoute). In the component where you want to reload on route reuse you can do this:

```
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = (
 future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
 curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot
) => {
 if (future.url.toString() === curr.url.toString()) {
  // reload the page
 }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in a much simpler way. Below is a small sample code:

in routing.module: "/product/: id / details"

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from ‘@angular/router’;

export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.paramsChange(params.id);
    });

}

// Call this method on page load
ngOnInit() {
}

// Call this method on change of the param
paramsChange(id) {
}
```

The general explanation is ... why to destroy already existed component instance and create a new one for the same case when it causes performance degradation?

It is the exactly the same behavior as using routes pattern `/product/:id` where the same component instance is also kept for `/product/5`, `/product/6`, ...

So you should re-init the component on the base of some emitted event (resolver/guard) and not on the base of `OnInit` hook because of the same component instance.